# FtpWebRequest times out when running more than 2 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically remove the 2 connection limit in WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866350/how-can-i-programmatically-remove-the-2-connection-limit-in-webclient)

My FTP script was working great until I started to try and run multiple threads at once. After excessive debugging it turns out the `FtpWebRequest` simply times out if two other threads are already doing something. (Uploading, checking if a file/directory exists or creating a directory.)

I already tried implementing a lock in the ftp class so that only one thread can ever create an `FtpWebRequest` at a time (and then close the lock when getting the response ofc) but that didn't help.

Each request uses it's own `FtpWebRequest` object so I'm not quite sure why this is happening. I can upload 10 files simultaneously to the same FTP server when using the `FileZilla` client so I can't imagine it's a problem on the server's end.

Is there some static behind-the-scenes thing in .NET that is causing this issue?

**Example function that times out >2 threads:**

```
public class ftp
{
    private string host = null;
    private string user = null;
    private string pass = null;
    private int bufferSize = 2048;

    /* Construct Object */
    public ftp(string hostIP, string userName, string password) { host = hostIP; user = userName; pass = password; }

    private object fileFolderCheckLock = new object(); //Only check if a file/dir exists one thread at a time
    private object requestLock = new object(); //Don't create multiple ftprequests simultaneously. Exit this lock when the response is being received.

    /* Create a New Directory on the FTP Server */
    public bool CreateDirectory(string newDirectory)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
        FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
        try
        {
            lock(requestLock)
            {
                if(!newDirectory.EndsWith("/")) newDirectory += "/";
                //Console.WriteLine("chk: "+host + "/" + newDirectory);
                Uri theuri = new Uri(host + "/" + newDirectory);
                //Console.WriteLine("theuri: "+theuri.ToString());
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(theuri);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                ftpRequest.Timeout = 10000;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){ Console.WriteLine("CreateDirectory Exception"+ex.ToString()); }
        finally
        {
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            try{ftpResponse.Close();}catch(Exception){}//??
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably hitting the default maximum connections.  Take a look at this: [How can I programmatically remove the 2 connection limit in WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866350/how-can-i-programmatically-remove-the-2-connection-limit-in-webclient)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.. all those hours wasted for something this simple, argh! I have decided to blame Microsoft ^^ Thx for your answer!

Comment: Bottom line is I called this in Main(): `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;`