# 'System.Net.WebException' in HtmlAgilityPack using Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, parallel.foreach

I have a web scraper that processes about 2,000 pages that I've tried to speed up by using a Parallel.ForEach loop.  My current code (trimmed for brevity) is:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dataTable1.AsEnumerable(), row =>
{
    scrape();
}
);

public void scrape()
{
    HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.website.com");
    doScraping(doc);
}
```

When this used a regular `foreach` loop, it worked.  Now, it will process some number of rows and then I start getting the following exceptions when trying to retrieve the `HTMLDocument`:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll

The Operation Has Timed Out

What causes the timeout to happen when operating in the Parallel loop?  It will get through the first 150-300 rows and then will timeout for each subsequent row.

Comment: Sounds like the site you want to scrap blocks you because of the huge amount of request you do in parallel, which looks to them like a DOS attack.

Comment: @shriek: I don't think think the site is blocking me.  I am able to access it from a browser while I'm continuously getting timeout errors.  Also, if I restart the application, it works again temporarily.

Comment: Adding in new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 } seems to reduce my problem to a very occasional timeout.  I'm running the app on a 4 core processor.  I'm still curious why parallel doesn't handle this better.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have a limit on the maximum number of simultaneous HttpWebRequest connections to a site. Check this .NET setting: [ConnectionManagement Element (Network Settings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx).

You can also do it programmatically: [How can I programmatically remove the 2 connection limit in WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866350/how-can-i-programmatically-remove-the-2-connection-limit-in-webclient)

It works with a browser in parallel because it uses another process.