# How to allow for a multi-threaded process to use as much ressource as multiple processes

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, parallel-processing, shared-memory

I wrote a program that spawns a user chosen number of threads that each crawl the internet in search of some data, you might call it a webcrawler.

The bottleneck of the program should definitely be network capacity since any given thread spends the majority of it's time waiting on network requests:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://averynice.web.api?x=2d2d2&?y=dwdwdw";
string response = client.DownloadString(url)
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the program will reach it's peak speed (in terms of how many web-pages it has processed) if I make it spawn about 20 threads, that speed being about 1,000 pages per minute. Any more threads than that and it's speed becomes correlated negatively to how many threads I add.

On the other hand, if I launch 10 or even 20 separate instances of the program and spawn 20 threads into each, all instances of the program will reach the same top speed resulting in a cumulative speed of 1000 per minute * number of program instances running.

I read here on stackoverflow that:

> Both processes and threads are independent sequences of execution. The
>   typical difference is that threads (of the same process) run in a
>   shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces.

So I figure the problem is in the size of the shared memory space, but how do I change that so that I could have a single instance running as many threads as my network capacity will handle?

If the problem isn't shared memory space then what is the limiting factor/bottleneck and how might I work around it?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions :).

Comment: There is a default limit of 2 simultaneous connections. The answers to this question describe how to change that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/866350/517852

Comment: The shared memory space mentioned is actually the process virtual address space that is being shared among its threads. Its size is 2 GiB on 32-bit Windows versions (or 3 GiB if the special 3/1 tuning option is in effect) and much more on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @mikez This is absolutely beautiful. Please submit an answer to my question and I will un-accept the current one in favor of yours which solved my problem with a single line of code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `WebClient` instances (in the same AppDomain) are limited to active 2 connections by default. You can change this programmatically by setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` property. This can also be configured using app.config. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/866350/517852) shows several options for changing the limit. Just make sure the web api doesn't block you for making too many requests!

Comment: Thank you very much, my program now runs at full speed with a single process running about 300 threads at which point the cpu becomes the bottlebeck when it reaches about 80% load. That or network capacity, hard to tell but not important.