# WebService duration time in IIS timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, web-services, iis

I have problem. I send multiple request to IIS Web Service (written in c# and .net platform). Every call need about 20 sec to proces. When I send 350 request, I get only half responses, and half time outs:

> The operation has timed out

What to change, to correct process all requests.

Comment: All. Or nothing. It will be difficult to help you with just this description.

Comment: This is too broad - obviously there are some hardware/software limits for number of threads/simultaneously open connections/etc. As always generic solution is to use "queue" - instead of processing the request itself, persist it into some storage (db/xml/cloud/whatever) and write batch (service) that will process the queue. If you want us to help with speedup you'll need to highlight what you're actually doing in the slow service calls.

Comment: I have console batch, that call web service, and want to take multithreding. At this moment I'm using  Parallel.For(0, clientsId.Length,i =>  { Thread.Sleep(TaskDelaySeconds * 1000 * i); } , and I want to get rid of this Thread.Sleep

Comment: @zchpit - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866350/how-can-i-programmatically-remove-the-2-connection-limit-in-webclient also as I've stated you might have problem with scalability on server, not on client